# Simple group by not working on datetime field?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me out with this?  I'm not sure why my group by isn't working.

```
SELECT [Date], SUM(counted) as TotalCount
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY [Date], TotalCount
ORDER BY [Date]
```

result

```
Date                        TotalCount

2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 12 
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 14 
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 11
```

I'm wanting the result to look like the following

```
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 37
```

Thanks

This MSSQLServer 2008, and I want to group by the date and time.

Comment: You want to group by the date only?, or by the date and time?. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried this on SQL Server 2008, and its working fine for me. As Lamak mentioned. it may be a problem with the time part of your field. it will be great if you can give some more info about server, table data etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `GROUP BY [Date], TotalCount` instead you need `GROUP BY [Date]`

This would cause an error though unless you also had a column in your source of that name, e.g. as below.

```
;WITH TableName([Date], counted, TotalCount) as
(
select '2011-09-07 00:00:00.000',12,1 union all
select '2011-09-07 00:00:00.000',14,2 union all 
select '2011-09-07 00:00:00.000',11,3
)
SELECT [Date], SUM(counted) as TotalCount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY [Date], TotalCount
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: +1 thanks, it's been a while since I used SQL.  Looks like LINQ is taking away my skills lol.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the time part of your field. If you want to group by only the date, then you can try the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[Date],112) [Date], SUM(Counted) TotalCount
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[Date],112)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the possibility of different values due to ticks, you might want to convert the Date into CHAR and do a group by.